# $\int_0^\infty -\frac{\log(|1-x|) dx}{x(2-x)} = \frac{3 \pi^2}{8}$ but Integrate gives $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm running Mathematica 13.0 Student Edition on Windows 10.

Consider the function $f(x) = -\frac{\log(|1-x|)}{x(2-x)}$. The function is well-defined at $0$ and $2$ and has a weak, integrate-able logarithmic divergence at $x=1$. The function is also positive everywhere on the real line.

Note that the function decays sufficiently rapidly so that it can be integrated from $0$ to $\infty$ without trouble. I can show that $$\int_0^\infty -\frac{\log(|1-x|) dx}{x(2-x)} = \frac{3 \pi^2}{8}.$$

This is indeed what `NIntegrate` finds numerically. However, I have the following perplexing result where `Integrate` is off by a factor of $2/3$ smaller than the correct answer:
[image: Showing the discrepancy]

---

Perhaps a key to what's happening can also be seen in the integral from $0$ to $1$ - as noted above, the function $f(x)$ is positive on the real line, so the fact `Integrate` gives zero is a sign of something going awry:

[image: Showing integral vanishes]

---

Here is the key code I used above for straightforward copy-pasting:

`Integrate[-1/(x (2 - x)) Log[Abs[1 - x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]` and `Integrate[-1/(x (2 - x)) Log[Abs[1 - x]], {x, 0, 1}]`

---

Why is this happening? Does it happen in other versions of Mathematica?

Comment: On Win7-x64 running v12.2.0, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxRJe.png).

Comment: Both v11.3 and 13.0 on Windows 10 give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks all, good to see!

Comment: v13.2.0 on MacOS 13.2 also gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest version that I have to yours is

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

RepeatedTiming[
 Integrate[-Log[Abs[1 - x]]/(x(2 - x)),
  {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* {8.69404, (3 π^2)/8} *)

RepeatedTiming[
 Integrate[-Log[RealAbs[1 - x]]/(x(2 - x)),
  {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* {8.93449, (3 π^2)/8} *)
```

However, since

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, Abs[1 - x] == Sqrt[(1 - x)^2] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

then

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Integrate[-Log[Sqrt[(1 - x)^2]]/(x(2 - x)),
  {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* {0.851492, (3 π^2)/8} *)
```

This form is much faster which indicates that it is much easier to work with. Check whether your version/OS gives the correct result with this alternate representation.

Comment: Great thinking! I'm getting the correct answers now. I'll have to remember this as an alternative to Abs.